Move javascript libaries etc.. off google hosts
I got this message

Chinese Language Stack Exchange requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load.

Seeing as this site caters to Chinese language learners perhaps it would be bests to host the javascript libraries on a server that's not owned by google.

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js

Seeing as google services doesn't work too well in China for some reason.

We already had a built-in per-site setting that allows us to host jQuery from our own cdn (cdn.sstatic.com), which I enabled for chinese.SE and it's child meta (this site).

Good idea! This page lists a few Chinese CDNs in particular that should be fast in China (Baidu, Sina): http://chineseseoshifu.com/blog/china-hosted-javascript-libraries-jquery-dojo-boostrap.html
This SO question shows how it can be done, using a fallback (so everyone uses Google first, then a secondary CDN): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607425/is-googles-cdn-for-jquery-available-in-china
